# How to use a method in multiple models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dry

I have two models User and Photo

Photo includes the following method:

```
      def passedTime datetime
        (datetime > (Date.today - 1.year)) ? ((distance_of_time_in_words datetime,   Date.today) + ' ago') : datetime.strftime('%d %b %Y')
      end
```

How do I include this method in the user model in a best practice way?

Comment: Use a module ("mixin"), a concern, a decorator, a helper, ...

Comment: And where should I put that, so thats automatically available in all models?

Comment: Check out https://gist.github.com/dhh/1014971 and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html for a starter

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can just put the method in a module in the lib folder and then include it in both models. Also, as a convention, you should stick to `snake_case` when declaring methods.

```
# lib/date_time.rb

module DateTime

  def passed_time datetime
    (datetime > (Date.today - 1.year)) ? ((distance_of_time_in_words datetime, 
    Date.today)    + ' ago') : datetime.strftime('%d %b %Y')
  end
end
```

Now include the module in both models

```
# User.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
include DateTime

# Photo.rb

Class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
include DateTime
```

Comment: When I include DateTime in User.rb or Photo.rb it raises the following error: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)

Comment: See my updated answer about the include after the class declaration. Did you make sure everything is correct syntactically with the method name snake case and the module. Aso make sure you are calling the method on an instance of the class. If you still are not sure, post another question with the code so we can see how you are using the module